# Using IExtenderProvider to provide a Type property

Tags: c#, winforms, iextenderprovider

I am trying to add a Type property to some controls in my WinForms designer. I would ideally like them to be serialised using typeof(MyCompany.TheTypeIUsed) (ala the way BindingSource.DataSource can be serialized).

Putting aside the fact I have not specified a designer for the type, it appears that if I add an IExtenderProvider that uses 'Type', the property WILL NOT appear in the property grid. If I use int or string or any other type it works fine.

Is this a bug in the IExtenderProvider implementation or are extra attributes etc required?

```
[ProvideProperty("CommandType", typeof (Control))]
public class TypeExtender : Component, IExtenderProvider
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Control, Type> controlCommands;

    public TypeExtender()
    {
        controlCommands = new Dictionary<Control, Type>();
    }

    #region impl

    bool IExtenderProvider.CanExtend(object target)
    {
        var control = target as Control;
        if (control == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public Type GetCommandType(Control obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            Debug.Fail("Non Control provided to Type getter");
            return null;
        }
        Type commandType;
        if (controlCommands.TryGetValue(obj, out commandType))
        {
            return commandType;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void SetCommandType(Control obj, Type value)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            Debug.Fail("Non control provided to Command Setter");
            return;
        }
        if (value == null)
        {
            controlCommands.Remove(obj);
        }
        else
        {
            controlCommands[obj] = value;
        }
    }

    [UsedImplicitly]
    private bool ShouldSerializeCommand(object c)
    {
        var control = c as Control;
        if (control == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        Type type;
        if (controlCommands.TryGetValue(control, out type))
        {
            return type != null;
        }

        return false;
    }

    [UsedImplicitly]
    private void ResetCommand(object c)
    {
        if (c is Control)
        {
            controlCommands.Remove(c as Control);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```